# Dictionary comprehension to group keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to use a dictionary comprehension to group keys in a dictionary?

```
d = {0: ("A",), 1: ("BB",), 2: ("BB",), 3: ("D",), 4: ("E",)}
l = [(0, 1, 2, 4), (3,)]
```

to produce:

```
d = {(0, 1, 2, 4): ("A","BB", "E"), (3,): ("D",)}
```

**UPDATE**:

I originally had the values as sets but have changed this to tuples. A `tuple(set(x))` operation could be used when creating `("A","BB", "E")` instead of `("A","BB","BB","E")`

Comment: You cannot use a set as a key because it is not hashable. You need to convert it to a sorted tuple or frozenset

Comment: @TrebuchetMS and @nicholishen; Yes that is true. I could use frozenset or tuple(set(x)) in order to achieve the same effect.

Comment: You need to drop the parens in `l` to make a list of two tuples instead of one nested tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `defaultdict`. Also note that I changed the format of `l` a bit, I don't think it should contain nested tuples.

```
d = {0: ("A",), 1: ("BB",), 2: ("BB",), 3: ("D",), 4: ("E",)}
l = [(0, 1, 2, 4), (3,)]

output = defaultdict(list)

for key_group in l:
    output[key_group].extend(d[key] for key in key_group)

print(output)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(0, 1, 2, 4): [('A',), ('BB',), ('BB',), ('E',)], (3,): [('D',)]})
```

The values in `output` are lists of tuples since `tuples` are immutable. The below snippet will produce an output which is closer to the output you provided by flattening the values (except for using lists as values insted of tuples for the same reason):

```
d = {0: ("A",), 1: ("BB",), 2: ("BB",), 3: ("D",), 4: ("E",)}
l = [(0, 1, 2, 4), (3,)]

output = defaultdict(list)

for key_group in l:
    output[key_group].extend(chain.from_iterable(set(d[key] for key in key_group)))

print(output)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(0, 1, 2, 4): ['A', 'E', 'BB'], (3,): ['D']})
```

For completeness, the code from OP's answer which uses `defaultdict(set)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

d = {0: ("A",), 1: ("BB",), 2: ("BB",), 3: ("D",), 4: ("E",)}
l = [(0, 1, 2, 4), (3,)]

output = defaultdict(set)

for key_group in l:
    output[key_group].update(chain.from_iterable(d[key] for key in key_group))
print(output)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {(0, 1, 2, 4): {'BB', 'A', 'E'}, (3,): {'D'}})
```

Comment: You could actually use defaultdict(set)?

Answer (score 2):

This answer demonstrates a solution using simple loops and comprehensions. Thus, it may not be as effective as other answers.

These are your pre-defined variables, note that I removed one depth from `l` (similar to DeepSpace's answer).

```
d = {0: ("A",), 1: ("BB",), 2: ("BB",), 3: ("D",), 4: ("E",)}
l = [(0, 1, 2, 4), (3,)]
```

Using normal loops:

```
w_normal = {}
for i in l:
  temp = []
  for j in i:
    temp += [d[j]]
  w_normal[tuple(i)] = temp
```

Using a dictionary comprehension (as requested):

```
w_comp = {tuple(i): [d[j] for j in i] for i in l}
```

Both values output when printed

```
{(0, 1, 2, 4): [('A',), ('BB',), ('BB',), ('E',)], (3,): [('D',)]}
```

Rather than using `tuple(set(x))` to create `[('A',), ('BB',), ('E',)]`, preserving `[('A',), ('BB',), ('BB',), ('E',)]` will allow you to index `('BB',)` and `('E',)` with respect to the key-tuple.

However, if you're persistent you could do the `tuple(set(x))` with

```
w_comp = {tuple(i): tuple({d[j] for j in i}) for i in l}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to DeepSpace's but using a defaultdict(set).

```
d = {0: ("A",), 1: ("BB",), 2: ("BB",), 3: ("D",), 4: ("E",)}
l = [(0, 1, 2, 4), (3,)]

output = defaultdict(set)

for key_group in l:
    output[key_group].update(d[key] for key in key_group)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the values in `output` will be nested, unlike your expected output

Comment: Maybe `output[key_group].update(chain.from_iterable(d[key] for key in key_group))`. This will output `defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {(0, 1, 2, 4): {'BB', 'A', 'E'}, (3,): {'D'}})`

Comment: I've added that to my asnwer as well